# aggregate columns with sum and group by

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df_new :

```
PageId    OSBrowser    VolumePred   ConversionPred
    A      (11, 16)         10        40
    B      (11, 16)         20        50
    D      (11, 16)         10        10
    C      (11, 17)         30        10
    E      (11, 17)         10        10
```

I try to aggregate pageId by OSBrowser and calculate sum by group.

For example the expected result should be :

```
PageId        OSBrowser    VolumePred   ConversionPred
A, B, D       (11, 16)          40        100

C, E          (11, 17)          40        20
```

I try with this code :

```
final_df=df_new.groupby(['OSBrowser']).agg({'PageId','VolumePred':'sum'})
```

But I got this error :

> ```
> final_df=df_new.groupby(['OSBrowser']).agg({'PageId','VolumePred':'sum'})
>                                                                  ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

Any idea please to help me to fix it ?  thanks

Comment: need `{'PageId':', '.join,'VolumePred':'sum', 'ConversionPred': 'sum'}`

Comment: @jezrael thank you for your help but I got this error when i try your code :  TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found

Comment: try `{'PageId': lambda x: ', '.join(x.dropna()),'VolumePred':'sum', 'ConversionPred': 'sum'}`

Comment: @jezrael i am sorry but the the same error with the new code :/

Comment: hmmm, `{'PageId': lambda x: ', '.join(x.dropna().astype(str)),'VolumePred':'sum', 'ConversionPred': 'sum'}` working ?

Comment: @jezrael \o/ Thank youuuu so much it works !!! \o/